# JFrame won't display JPanel or JCheckBoxes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

For some reason, my JFrame won't display either of the two. 
Note, my JFrame is made in another class and accessed from that. 
Also, I would like tips on how my code is presented and designed if thats okay?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GuiDrugContents {

 private JPanel panel;

 public GuiDrugContents(ArrayList<String> drug_names){

        // Firstly create the panel for the checkboxes to be held.
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.panel = panel;

        testmain.frame.add(panel);

          // Now create an array list of checkboxes.
        ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
        checkboxes = getCheckBoxes(drug_names);

        // Now add the JPanel to the JFrame
                testmain.frame.add(panel);

        // Now add these checkboxes to the JPanel.
        addCheckBoxes(checkboxes);

        testmain.frame.repaint();

    }
    /**
     * Takes an array list of JCheckBoxes and adds each one to the panel.
     */
    private void addCheckBoxes(ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes) {
        for(JCheckBox checkbox: checkboxes){
            panel.add(checkbox);
        }

    }
    /**
     * Takes the array list of drug names as strings and makes an array list
     * of JCheckBoxes out of these. 
     * @param drug_names
     * @return
     */
    private ArrayList<JCheckBox> getCheckBoxes(ArrayList<String> drug_names) {
        ArrayList<JCheckBox> arraylist = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
        for(String drug_name: drug_names){
            JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox(drug_name);
            arraylist.add(checkbox);
        }
        return arraylist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is no checkboxes?  Better if you can re-write into a stand-alone minimal class that we can paste into eclipse and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I guessing, but you probably need to call `revalidate` before `repaint`

Comment: I tried revalidating it, and what its done is only created the last CheckBox... Is it because CheckBox objects cannot be created in a loop as the next CheckBox just replaces the previous? I think so..

Comment: Yes, combo boxes can be created in an loop, but your panel is using a `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @MadProgrammer your panel is using a `BorderLayout`, probably you wanted to use a `BoxLayout` to place them vertically.

I created this example which creates a borizontal or vertical align for check boxes depending which line you comment.

[`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for horizontal align

[image]

[`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for vertical align

[image]

From your comment:

> I tried revalidating it, and what its done is only created the last CheckBox... Is it because CheckBox objects cannot be created in a loop as the next CheckBox just replaces the previous? I think so..

And also as @MadProgrammer has already answered in his comment, yes, you can create them in a loop, that's what I did in my following example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class CheckBoxesInALoop {
    JFrame frame;
    JCheckBox box;
    JPanel boxPane, buttonPane;
    JButton button;
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new CheckBoxesInALoop();
    }

    public CheckBoxesInALoop() {
        frame = new JFrame("Boxes added in a loop");
        boxPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("I do nothing");

        boxPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //Horizontal add
        //boxPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(boxPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); //Vertical add

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //Change for your array list boxes
            box = new JCheckBox("I am the " + (i + 1) + " checkbox"); //we re use the same "box" object (similar to your arraylist)
            boxPane.add(box);
        }
        buttonPane.add(button);

        frame.add(boxPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However in the future you should create a simple code as mine which is known as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). This will improve your questions and the number and quality of answers you might get.